# Nginx proxying 1935 to a subdirectory path?

Tags: nginx, rtmp

I have Ant Media Server running. It typically runs on the standard RTMP port `1935`. I've changed Ant to `11935` (works currently), and I want nginx to recieve `1935` and re-route it to `11935` (with a subdir).

So instead of streaming to `rtmp://server.com/LiveApp/[key]` you can stream to `rtmp://server.com/[key]`

`nginx.conf`

```
stream {
  server {
    listen 1935;
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:11935;
    proxy_buffer_size 32k;
  }
}
```

`sudo ufw status`

```
1935/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
1935/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

This works currently. I can stream to `rtmp://server.com/LiveApp/[key]` and it's fine. But now I want to proxy `rtmp://server.com/[key]` -> `rtmp://server.com:11935/LiveApp/[key]`

My (failed) attempt at adding it as an http proxy:

```
server {
  listen 1935;
  server_name _;

  location ~/(.*)$ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass localhost:11935/LiveApp/$1;
  }
}
```